# Bash Variable Not Being Assigned

Tags: bash, variable-assignment

I have this bash script, that gets an input from the user, and returns a phonetic transcription of the word, even if no transcription is available. However, the variable results isn't being assigned as a blank line is being printed instead of the value inside.

I have tried putting the commands into a different script, and that also produced blank lines, and doubled checked that there was no space between results and =

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#check if user entered a word to translate to ipa
#if a word was not entered prompt the user to enter a word
#else set the word passed as an argument to the variable current
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo "You did not enter a word for translation, Please enter one now: "
  read current
else
  current=$1
fi

#confirm to user the word they entered
echo "The word you chose for translation: $current"

#format the word into '< w o r d >'
onmt_word=$(python ONMT_DATA_FORMAT.py "$current")
#write over current word in temp_word.txt
echo $onmt_word > temp_word.txt

#translate the word in temp_word.txt using openNMT with the model created from a set of 32k words
results=$(onmt_translate -gpu -1 -model eng_ipa_model1_steps/eng_ipa_model1_step_100000.pt -src temp_word.txt -replace_unk -verbose -output model1_step_10000_temp_pred)
#print only the results we care about, i.e. the translated IPA
echo "The provided IPA translation is:"
echo $results | egrep -o '< .* >'
echo "Please ignore the first and last symbol, these are needed for the translation process."
```

Source:
https://github.com/LonelyRider-cs/LING4100_project

Comment: Does `onmt_translate` print anything to stdout?  (Judging by the `-output` flag, I'm guessing it does not.)

Comment: Which variable is coming out blank, `$onmt_word` or `$results` or something else? It might help to put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so it prints an execution trace as it runs. Also, you should double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$var"` instead of `echo $var`), though I don't think that'd cause a blank output problem.

Comment: @JohnGordon onmt_translate is part of the ONMT library (https://pypi.org/project/OpenNMT-py/1.2.0/) and is the last step for the model.

Comment: @GordonDavisson To clarify, it is $results that is showing up as empty

Comment: Is the output in a file named `model1_step_10000_temp_pred`?

Comment: The output is in that file. If possible, my goal was to have the output in the bash file, so I could grab the output with python, without opening and reading files

Comment: The whole issue looks more like using `omnt_translate` properly, and since we don't know this program, it is difficult to help here. I suggest that you first convince this tool to write its result to stdout. Once you are done, I don't see why you would need the variable `results`, because you could equally well do a `omnt_translate ... | egrep ....` directly. Actually, your `echo` would  (in the way you wrote it) modify the output, in that it squeezes any run of spaces into a single space. I'm not sure that this is what you want.